# Probabilistic notation for modulo null-events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have any kind of relationship, say for example inclusion. Suppose we have two nonnegligible events $A$ and $B$ such that for almost every $\omega\in A$, $\omega\in B$. Then I would like to say that $A\subseteq B$ modulo a null event: is there a standard probabilistic notation for the operator $\subseteq$ interpreted only modulo null-events? Obviously one can just make one up, like $\subseteq_{\mathbb{P}}$ but I wonder if there is already something standard.

Comment: $\mathbb P(A\setminus B)=0$,  or equivalently, $\mathbb P(A^c\cup B)=1\,.$

Comment: perhaps I was not clear: I was asking if there is a standard way of modifying the operator notation $\subset$ to express the modulo null-event compactly.

Comment: your notation is standard but does not uses $\subseteq$, that is why I specify 'probabilistic notation for the operator $\subseteq$.

Comment: You were absolutely clear. Imho my notation is much clearer than some sort of $\subset_{\mathbb P}\,.$ If you use that fine but don't forget to mention what it means.

Comment: An issue with $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus B)=0$ is that there is loss of information: the sets $A$ and $B$ could even be disjoint and still have $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus B)=0$. All the information about the inclusion part is gone with such notation.

Comment: If that's the case (which I don't believe) I'd like to ask you to elaborate what else $\subseteq_{\mathbb P}$ means if not what I wrote. You find in me a mathematician who has zero trust in  a notation in itself. If an author is not able to define it it is meaningless.

Comment: My bad I got confused

Comment: Sounds good. A fairly standard notation for $A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A$ is the symmetric difference $A\Delta B\,.$ This would allow to define $A=_{\mathbb P}B$ as $\mathbb P(A\Delta B)=0\,.$

Comment: The definition is given in the statement: for almost every $\omega\in A$, $\omega\in B$. My only issue here is finding something easy to write but standard. Otherwise, one can just add 'modulo null-events' next to $A\subset B$ or stick with $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus B)$ as you say, if nothing standard is available. I do not like to make up notations either.

Comment: I see, that seems to validate the use of $\subset_{\mathbb{P}}$ then... thank you, I never run into it!

Comment: Notations are to be made up in order to make formulas easier to read. They should be defined before used (unless they are standard from Calculus I) and that's it.

Comment: I don't think any such notation has been wildly adopted in the literature, so it is completely up to you to come up with such a one (provided you clearly introduce the definition before it is used). Or, we may rely on the existing notation, especially by noting that $A\subset_{\mathbf{P}}B$ if and only if $\mathbf{1}_A\leq\mathbf{1}_B$ holds $\mathbf{P}$-almost surely.